# How to prevent faking value of localStorage and login

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on an authentication system, implemented the front end using vuejs and back end with nodejs. User is able to register and login successfully. I am verifying user is logged in using jwt token. My problem is anyone can login by manipulating the localStorage jwt token value. Is there anyway to prevent it.

Comment: You don't need to prevent it - session cookies has the same "problem" for years. Generate a secure token and validade server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a step by step of how your server should prevent someone from changing their JWT info:

1. Your NodeJS server creates a new JWT using an encryption key (we'll call it `secret-key`) to create the signature, and it sends the token to the client.
2. The user decides they want admin access, so they change their permissions in their local JWT and send it to the server.
3. The NodeJS server re-signs the header and payload of the user's JWT using `secret-key` and compares that generated signature with the signature in the user's JWT. If they match, then nothing has changed about the user's JWT. If they don't match, then either the user changed something in the header or payload, or they tried re-signing the token with their own encryption key. Either way, your server can tell that the JWT isn't valid, and you can deny them access.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using an asymmetric signature on your JWT token, and the private key should be available only to the server that creates the JWT.  If this is the case, then it's highly unlikely that a user would be able to forge JWT claims.

Comment: Thanks. That''s very helpful to me.